# how to get event of mousescroll on grid in extjs?

Tags: extjs

I have grid and action column in this grid. When I click on action column on grid it displays menu. when I clicked anywhere else after menu shown, menu gets hide.

But when I scroll grid with mouse wheel, menu doesn't hide. Instead its position changes as per scrolling...so I want solution for this to handle this situation so that I can hide menu on mouse-wheeel scroll

Answer (score 0):

Hi Could you please add this in the afterRender of your grid

```
this.body.on('scroll', this.handleScroll);


handleScroll: function() {

               //hide your menu.

        },
```

Hope it helps you.